# Kafka Storage Exception

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am getting this **Kafka Storage Exception : Halting due to unrecoverable IO error in handling produce requests** exception periodically in every 3-4 days from some time. It causes my broker to shutdown which causes uncommitted offsets resulting in loss of data.

Can someone please suggest reason for the same.

Comment: Please add more logs, as this is not sufficient to understand.

Comment: Might be related to open file handles on your OS

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons could be If you are using windows machine to run kafka broker.Kafka logs might be getting stored in windows drive(C:) . Try changing the kafka logs Dir from C: drive to D: \ drive and never faced the issue.

Ensure that you disk has enough space.
Try deleting Kafka-logs dir(Please do not even think of trying this in production) and perform zookeeper logs clean up as well.